# QFileDialog causes my application to become less responsive

Tags: c++, windows, qt

Firstly, for context, I am connecting a signal from `triggered` from QAction to a slot called `fileOpen` in `this`, and other similar connections are done in a method in my main window class like the following:

```
void MainWindow::createActions()
{
    m_fileNew = new QAction("&New", this);
    m_fileOpen = new QAction("&Open", this);
    m_fileExit = new QAction("E&xit", this);
    connect(m_fileNew, SIGNAL(triggered(bool)), this, SLOT(fileNew()));
    connect(m_fileOpen, SIGNAL(triggered(bool)), this, SLOT(fileOpen()));
    connect(m_fileExit, SIGNAL(triggered(bool)), this, SLOT(fileExit()));
}
```

To show the file dialog, the static method `QFileDialog::getOpenFileName` is used in `MainWindow::fileOpen`:

```
void MainWindow::fileOpen()
{
    QString filename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open Audio File"),
                                 "", tr("WAVE Files (*.wav);;All Files (*.*)"));
    if (filename != QString::null) {
        m_fileName = filename;
    }
}
```

The signal-slot connection between `m_fileOpen` and `fileOpen` works and displays the file dialog, but after closing the dialog the window takes longer to redraw while resizing.

Why is that happening, and how can I fix it?

Comment: What do you do with `m_fileName` after it's set?  Does performance degrade even if you cancel the file dialog rather than selecting a file?

Comment: @G.M. Nothing is done with `m_fileName` at the moment. The observable performance degradation is the same regardless of the file dialog being cancelled or accepted.

Comment: If you are looking to implement a responsive, reliable UI, you cannot possibly consider Qt. With that out of the way, isolate the issue, produce a reproducible test case, and file a defect report.

Comment: if on Windows, a FileDialog could load some Windows dlls that may unload by themselves after sometime. But those are generally not related to drawing. Also it changes your current directory to the selected file's location.

Comment: One thing you might try is passing an [`options`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getOpenFileName) parameter of `QFileDialog::Options() | QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog` to `QFileDialog::getOpenFileName`.

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was build my Qt application in release mode, which means removing the "CONFIG+=debug" argument from the qmake call.

In release mode the performance degradation is gone, which is great, although I don't understand what differences between the debug and release versions of the Qt libraries allow this to occur.

Comment: The performance degradation is still there in a Release configuration. It's just not as pronounced as it is in a Debug build (the difference is mostly one of compiler optimizations and sanity checks in debug mode).